# how to use htaccess to deny browser request url but not the RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to deny direct access to a file but provide the file with RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^/image/([^/]+).jpg$ /image.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^/image.php [L, R=404]
```

I expect localhost/image.php to return error 404
but it returns 404 also for localhost/image/image.jpg

Comment: The code you’ve posted in htaccess is not doing anything and it’s syntactically invalid (so should be generating an error on Apache)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of directives matters!

Specifically, the `mod_rewrite` Apache module processes rules *in order* on each request, and *later rules see the URL manipulated by earlier rules*.

This is in fact what the `[L]` flag you have used is for - it is short for `[last]`, and means "don't process any more rules for this request, in the current context". A [slightly stronger form is `[END]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end), meaning "don't process any more rules for this request, even if the new URL would re-process an `.htaccess` file or `<Directory>` block".

---

In your current rules, here's what happens to a request for `/image/hello.jpg`:

1. The pattern `^/image/([^/]+).jpg$` is tested against `/image/hello.jpg`, matches, and rewrites the URL to `/image.php?name=hello`
2. The pattern `^/image.php` is tested against *the rewritten URL*, `/image.php?name=hello`, matches, and issues a 404

---

If you put them the other way around:

```
RewriteRule ^/image.php [L, R=404]
RewriteRule ^/image/([^/]+).jpg$ /image.php?name=$1
```

Now, here's what happens to a request for `/image/hello.jpg`:

1. The pattern `^/image.php` is tested against `/image/hello.jpg`, `/image.php?name=hello`, doesn't match, so no change is applied
2. The pattern `^/image/([^/]+).jpg$` is tested against `/image/hello.jpg`, matches, and rewrites the URL to `/image.php?name=hello`
3. However, there's a risk that these directives are in a `.htaccess` file which will be re-processed, repeating step 1

---

If you also use `[END]` on both rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/image.php [END, R=404]
RewriteRule ^/image/([^/]+).jpg$ /image.php?name=$1 [END]
```

Now, here's what happens to a request for `/image/hello.jpg`:

1. The pattern `^/image.php` is tested against `/image/hello.jpg`, `/image.php?name=hello`, doesn't match, so no change is applied
2. The pattern `^/image/([^/]+).jpg$` is tested against `/image/hello.jpg`, matches, and rewrites the URL to `/image.php?name=hello`
3. The `[END]` flag ensures that no more rules are processed

---

In fact, adding `[END]` is enough in this case for it to work in either order:

```
RewriteRule ^/image/([^/]+).jpg$ /image.php?name=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/image.php [END, R=404]
```

1. The pattern `^/image/([^/]+).jpg$` is tested against `/image/hello.jpg`, matches, and rewrites the URL to `/image.php?name=hello`
2. The `[END]` flag ensures that no more rules are processed, so the `^/image.php` rule isn't even tested

Comment: if I use RewriteRule ^/image.php [END, R=404] it return 500, however if I use just [R=404] or [END] it works. do u know why?

Comment: @JonathanIvgi Hm, I might be wrong, but I think there's actually a syntax error in your rule: it should have a `-` for the rewrite target, _then_ the flags, i.e. `RewriteRule ^/image.php - [END, R=404]`  In which case, I'm not sure why it _ever_ works, maybe by accident!

Comment: still makes an error

Comment: @JonathanIvgi Not sure, then. A 500 error usually means something has been logged somewhere, so your next step should be to find some log files and hope for a more specific error.